# How to refresh directory using java

Tags: java

I have a java code in which i call shell script to extract zip files. After the script is run, i want to copy the extracted folder to some other location, but when i list the contents of folder i get only zip file and not the extracted one. 
My java code is as follows:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("/home/a/");
        File filenew = new File("/home/aaa/");
        File filenew1 = new File("/home/aaa/script/");
        File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
             if(dir.exists()){

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        for(File file1:files){
            System.out.println(file1.getName());
            if(file1.getName().equals("app_dir"))
            {
                System.out.println("Inside app");
            }
            else if(file1.getName().endsWith("zip"))
            {
                File srcDir = new File(file+"/"+file1.getName());
                File DestDir=new File("/home/aaa/script/*.zip");
                FileUtils.copyFile(srcDir, DestDir);
            }

            else if(file1.getName().endsWith("tar"))
            {
                File srcDir = new File(file+"/"+file1.getName());
                File DestDir=new File("/home/aaa/script/*.tar");
                FileUtils.copyFile(srcDir, DestDir);
            }

            else
            {
            deleteDir(file1);
            }
        }  
        try {
             ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","/home/aaa/myscript.sh");
                Process p = pb.start();
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        filenew1.canExecute();
     File[] filesnew1 = filenew1.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
             if(dir.exists()){

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        for(File file11:filesnew1){
            System.out.println(file11.getName());
            File f = new File(filenew+File.separator+"app_dir");
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(f, file);
        }   
    }
    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete(); // The directory is empty now and can be deleted.
    }
}
```

How do I refresh a folder?

Comment: Take a look on http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/265727-refresh-remote-folder/

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but mabye something is going on in the background? Maybe the OS needs more time to update the contents of the folder? Could you try a `Thread.sleep(5000);` before you copy the files?

Comment: You need to wait for the script to finish. Add after you have started the process `p.waitFor()`.

Comment: i added p.waitFor() but its taking lot of time

Comment: Hey thread.sleep worked such a silly mistake of mine. But thank u